How to retrieve or export the numeric data from a Chart.js canvas object
I want to retrieve the numeric data from a canvas object created with Chart.js in a website.
The website is https://microwave-cablebuilder.gore.com/builder.html
When a cable configuration is typed, e.g., using existing assembly (downwards):
part number: 0F0CB0CB0500
and maximum frequency (GHz): 70
and after clicking on Next (twice), a canvas is created (using Chart.js, I guess).
How to retrieve or export these data? (Without taking thousands of single points, one by one, from the canvas.)
I have inspected the code, but I am unable to find the data there.
I just can get the canvas object through:
ctx = document.getElementById("insertion-loss-chart")
I am expecting someone knowing how Chart.js canvas works and could tell me how to operate in the console of the web browser to retrieve the (X, Y) data, that is, the frequency in GHz and the typical / guaranteed insertion loss.

There's no "chart.js canvas object". The canvas element contains information about the pixel colors, but has no reference to chart.js or to the original data. You need to use the chart instance javascript object. The page you linked to seems to expose a Chart.instances object that you need to iterate through to find the one that contains your data (note that in general there is no need for such access to be available in the global space at all).

Finding the chart instance that holds data can be done through, e.g.,  chartWithData = Object.values(Chart.instances).find(chart => chart.data.datasets[0].data.length), and then browse the data key of that instance, e.g., chartWithData.data.datasets[0].data chartWithData.data.datasets[1].data
